Pyspark filter via like multiple conditions
I would like to use the following combination of like and any in pyspark in the most pythonic way.
This code I'm using in SQL works but I would like to get it working in python as well.
select
  *
from
  <catalog>.<schema>.<table>
where
  <column> like any (<constraint_1>,<constraint_2>,<constraint_3>)

I tried to use the method of https://www.statology.org/pyspark-contains-multiple-values/
But this doesn't work.
my_values = [<constraint_1>,<constraint_2>,<constraint_3>]
regex_values = "|".join(my_values)

sdf = spark.read.table(<catalog>.<schema>.<table>)
sdf = sdf.filter(sdf[<column>].like(regex_values))

The method I came up with only takes into account the first constraint
sdf = spark.read.table(<catalog>.<schema>.<table>)
sdf = sdf.filter(sdf[<column>].like(<constraint_1> or <constraint_2> or <constraint_3>))

I could use multiple conditions like in the example below but there are more then these 3 constraints and it gets could large really quick.
sdf = spark.read.table(<catalog>.<schema>.<table>)
sdf = sdf.filter(sdf[<column>].like(<constraint_1>) |
                 sdf[<column>].like(<constraint_2>) |
                 sdf[<column>].like(<constraint_3>))

The other option would be Using LIKE operator for multiple words in PySpark however this is not very pythonic.

I think your approach is right. You only need to use rlike in place of like. Here is an example. see if it helps!
ab=spark.createDataFrame([["<constraint_1>","bc","ef"],["<constraint_2>","ef","gf"],["<constraint_3>","ak","ka"]],schema=["one","two","three"])
search_strings=["constraint_1","constraint_3"]
regex_pattern = "|".join(search_strings)
filtered_df = ab.filter(col("one").rlike(regex_pattern))
filtered_df.display()


The only way I see here is to filter using F.expr on a constructed expression:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

constraints_list = [f'"{constr}"' for constr in constraints_list]
constraints = ', '.join(constraints_list)

sdf = sdf.filter(F.expr(f'{col_name} like ANY ({constraints})'))

Or in case of the large number of constraints you could just reduce your constraints like that:
from functools import reduce

constraints = (sdf[<column>].like(constraint) for constraint in constraints_list)

expr = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, constraints)

sdf = sdf.filter(expr)


You can try this:
my_values = ["angel", "bally", "chen"]
regex_values = "|".join(my_values)
sdf = spark.read.table("my_catalog.my_schema.my_table")
filtered_sdf = sdf.filter(sdf["fruit_column"].rlike(regex_values))
filtered_sdf.show()

